# Multiple variable storage in a plain text database format

Tags: shell-script, variable, echo, database

I've got some command outputs saved into variables in bash script, for instance 3, in each loop iteration. I'd like to save these variables inside a plain text database containing 3 fields before the iteration finishes

The  idea is the following:

```
If..

Command output1 > $v1
Command output2 > $v2
Command output3 > $v3

echo $v1 $v2 $v 3 >> database.txt

fi
```

Would the echo variable calling be valid for storing variables value into database.txt? What if we would like them to be delimited by tab in the plain text?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Why do you want to store variables in the text file? How do the variables look like? Can you give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar project i built, this one worked for me fine:

```
export TMPFILE=/tmp/yadvalues

function listselect { 
echo "Args Received = $0, $1 , $2 , $3 , $4 , $5" #Display args send to function 
echo -e "FILEID=\"$1\"\nFILENAME=\"$4\"\nFILECOMMAND=\"$5\"" > $TMPFILE
# Save some of the args in file
}
#export -f listselect

function filedisplay { 
source $TMPFILE 
ftd=$(yad --title="File Display-$FILENAME" --width=800 --height=500 \
--center --text-info --filename=$FILENAME --wrap --editable \
--button="Go Back":0)    
# Use var $FILENAME present in $TMPFILE
}
#export -f filedisplay
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted would capture the standard output of Command into filenames based on the *values* of the `$v1` & etc variables. If that is what you are doing, then: no, the echo statement at the end would not produce the *contents* of those three files, but rather the three file *names*.

If you want the output of those three commands to be saved, tab-delimited, into the `database.txt` file, then do something like:

```
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$(Command output1)" "$(Command output2)" "$(Command output3)" >> database.txt
```